# Wordpress add_filter 'template_include' not working

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
 * Plugin URI: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
 * Description: xxxxxxxxxx
 * Version: 2020/05/01
 * Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 * Author URI: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
 */

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

function ss_replace_text($page)
{
    return $page;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'ss_replace');

function ss_replace()
{
    ob_start();
    ob_start('ss_replace_text');
}
```

It returns nothing, it should return the page content to the browser.

Comment: try to have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ob-start.php . You never flush the output buffer

Comment: your function `ss_replace` should look like this: `ob_start('ss_replace_text'); ob_end_flush();` and between the ob_start and ob_end_flush you should echo the content you want to display

Comment: also, have a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/ and here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks for tips on how to use the filters

Comment: I want to replace some text in the webiste. The same code is working one website, but doesn't work on another website. So, how do I echo page content in between the ob_start and ob_end_flush? I tried:     ob_start(); $page = ob_start('ss_replace_text'); echo $page; ob_end_flush(); but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at how output buffers work in PHP [ob-start reference](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ob-start.php)

Then, you also need to understand how filters work. They basically take an argument ( which is the output ) send it to the filter and the filter needs to return ( not echo ) the modified output [This is a good reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)

Then, make sure that 'template_include' is the actual filter you want to use. That is usually used for loading a different file based on some conditions. I never used it for changing the output of the loaded file. [template_include filter reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/)

The code should look something like this:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'ss_replace');

function ss_replace( $template )
{
    ob_start('ss_replace_text');

    echo $template;

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: So, what would be the best way to replace text in a page? I copied code from: https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/ to replace text in any page

Comment: I copied the code of plugin in line 270: function far_template_redirect() that calls: function far_ob_call( $buffer ) { on line 255

Comment: I would probably just try to use the translations or override the loaded file in the child theme, copy the content from the file that needs to be changed and apply the changes in the new file from the child theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: your code works fine, but how do I add code to replace some text in $template? please suggest where to put 'str_replace' in your method? I tried hard, but failed to include the string replace anywhere.